Strongly typed claims in ASP.NET Core
I am writing an API in ASP.NET Core using C#. I have set up authentication with JWTs.
Now I want to implement authorization, for this I need to consume the JWT claims.
I can consume the claims directly from the ClaimsPrincipal in the HttpContext.User, but I rather have a class that holds the strongly typed JWT claims.
It looks something like this:
public class MyJwtClaims
{
    public int Sub { get; set; }
    public string Jti { get; set; }
    public DateTimeoffset Exp { get; set; }
    public DateTimeoffset Nbf { get; set; }
    public DateTimeoffset Iat { get; set; }
}

To accomplish this, I can create a ClaimsProviderService that will, access the ClaimsPrincipal, parse the claims and store the values in an instance of the MyJwtClaims class. I will need to register the ClaimsProviderService as scoped, to ensure the MyJwtClaims instance is limited to the http request lifetime. Something similar to this:
public class ClaimsProviderService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly Lazy<MyJwtClaims> claims;
    public MyJwtClaims Claims => claims.Value;

    public ClaimsProviderService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        claims = new Lazy<MyJwtClaims>(ParseClaims);
    }

    private MyJwtClaims ParseClaims()
    {
         // TODO: Parse claims
         // Access the HttpContext from httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
         // Access the ClaimsPrincipal from HttpContext.User
         return new MyJwtClaims();
    }
}

And then, register the service as scoped (either in startup.cs or program.cs):
services.AddScoped<ClaimsProviderService>();

This way, the ClaimsPrincipal is parsed, once per http request, into a strongly typed MyJwtClaims. All I need to do now is consume the ClaimsProviderService.
My question: is there any way to achieve something similar with a built-in service?
This is not a lot of code, but it certainly feels like I am missing an "out-of-the-box" solution already implemented in ASP.NET Core, and I would like to know all the options before making a decision.

Claim.Value is a string, so I think you're on the right track.  Just serialize MyJwtClaims, put it in the Claim.Value, and deserialize it when you need to access it.  There is also a ValueType property that allows you to differentiate between multiple classes.

The documentation doesn't appear to have a ClaimsPrincipal class that is strongly-typed, so you'll have to roll this yourself.  JWT claims are just strings, so it's up to you to create a strongly-typed infrastructure for them.  That said, Microsoft does provide some predefined claim types.

@RobertHarvey you are right, thank you. That is all good and great to consider in the ParseClaims method. But I was looking for an out of the box solution, for example (but not exactly) a generic ClaimsPrincipal that will allow me to store the strongly-typed claims would be great. Or any other similar solutions that do not require the overhead of an additional service in the DI

Do you really need another service?  Deserializing the claims to a strongly-typed object using Newtonsoft.Json is a single line of code.  Same for serialization.
